# Set Chart Background Image - Chart.js

Tags: jquery, charts, background-image, chart.js

I've searched on the internet and couldn't find a solution that seems to work for me.

I'm using Chart.js and I'm trying to set an image for the canvas background. So far I have tried setting the background in CSS like so

```
canvas {
   background-image: url(/Content/bg.png);
}
```

But the image doesn't show up. Can any point me in the right direction please. Maybe there is a property that can be set during the chart initialisation?

Comment: This should be working, are you sure that's the path to the image? Try an !important or try setting "background" instead of "background-image" as well to make sure that there isn't another style that is overriding yours.

Comment: I changed it to just background and it didnt work. Tried both the background and background-image with the !important tag and it also didnt work. I pasted the url into the browser and the image showed so its the correct url

Comment: Nope, its the same as whats in the OP

Comment: ehh, I feel like an idiot. The image I was using was a PNG and it was 8960px wide and my canvas was only 1200px. So the transparent part was showing on the canvas which made it look like the CSS wasnt working...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your css file:

canvas {
    background: url(http://www.imagenesdeamor.pro/wp-content/uploads/2016/11 /Imagenes-chidas-de-amor-6-320x320.jpg);
 }